# How to manage date time in order management system like foodpanda

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, datetime, windows-server-2012-r2

I am facing issue in managing date and time in order management system after midnight. Restaurant are showing open after 12AM. Please suggest the proper way to manage this issue.

I am using windows server 2012 in Amazon web services and apache and mysql.
The site is developed in php.

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: You are "facing an issue", but you don't tell us what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with technologies or platform you are using. It is an application issue. Few things you need to take care:

1. Install services like ntp which keeps time in sync of the server. But this is to make sure time is synced upto micro seconds. This is not an issue in ur case for now.
2. I think problem in your case is timezone.. which can be solved in multiple ways. Easiest solution would be to make sure that your database and server ( on which php ) is running are in same time zone as that of your country.. i.e. if your cusstomers/restaurants are from India; make sure your database and PHP server are on IST.. Then you don't have to worry about timezone issues.. but then this won't work if your customers are distributed in multiple countries. In that case, in your application you would always have to convert time to same timezone viz. IST.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your suggestion, I only require this for India. Previously we were saving the window server time in 24 hours format and then we were matching that with the current server time. But when the condition is 00.00.00 (i.e 12 AM) all restaurants which were supposed to be closed start showing open.

Comment: format wont make any difference; be it 12 hours or 24 hours format.. Until and unless in application you are matching TimeStamp objects and not matching time as strings.. Did you make sure both your database and php server are on IST ?

Comment: Sir when i am running the command: show variables like '%time_zone%' i am ending up by getting system_time_zone is Indian Standard Time and Time zone is System

Comment: Please tell me more details about ur problem like logic of Restaurant open !

Comment: Sir actually I am getting difficulty to validate the time which is stored in database with the actual time. As we are using Window Server 2012 R2 at AWS so we are taking the local time from the remote computer to validate with the time saved in database. According to that we are displaying Restaurant open/close in frontend. Also we are using time datatype in mysql.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer; make sure BOTH database and your PHP server are in same timezone. You can verify this by seeing time on both servers. Also, make sure that you are using datetime ( not ONLY date ) as data type at both places

Comment: Ok I have updated both db and php timezone to Asia/Kolkata. Well we are only concerned with time so we are only using time as datatype. Thanks a lot bro for all your help. I guess we are very close to solve this issue. Regards and thanks for your precious time and advice.